# Is it possible to programmatically hide Vuetify data-table items?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm wondering if there is a way to `hide` a whole row/item in a vuetify data-table. I've read threads about hiding columns but not data-table items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, You want to hide the specific rows from the `<v-data-table>`. If Yes, you can achieve that by using `v-slot` and manipulate the template.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert',
          value: 'name'
        }
      ],
      items: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          show: true
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          show: false
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          show: true
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          show: false
        }
      ]
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.6/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.6/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="items"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template v-slot:item="props">
    <template v-if="props.item.show">
      <tr>{{ props.item.name }}</tr>
    </template>
</template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the proper way to achieve it, in adition to what Rohit said, you don't need to add a `show` property to your array of items. You can add your own logic to check if an item will be visible or not inside your `v-if` by passing the item to a function and returning `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I think passing an empty array to your `:items` would fix your problem. or you can do this one `:items="defaultVales || desserts"`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best way to handle this is to add a `show` property to your objects and use a computed property to hide and show items

### Working example

Here it will hide column on `click`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  computed:{
    showItems(){
      return this.desserts.filter(x => x.show)
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [
        { text: 'Name', value: 'name' },
        { text: 'Score', value: 'score' },
      ],
      desserts: [{
          name: "Frozen",
          score: 66,
          show: true,
        },
        {
          name: "Tom",
          score: 100,
          show: true,
        },
        {
          name: "Eclair",
          score: 100,
          show: true,
        },
        {
          name: "Frozen",
          score: 89,
          show: true,
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    hideColumn(col){
      col.show = false
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.4/dist/vuetify.min.css'>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.4/dist/vuetify.min.js'></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-data-table
    :items="showItems"
    :headers="headers"
    @click:row="hideColumn"
  >
  
  </v-data-table>
</div>
```